# Waiting thread not resuming

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I've been making a game where a circles of decreasing size are drawn on the screen and with one finger pressed on the screen you must stay on these circles. If you come off the circles, you lose.

I'm trying to get this game to pause a thread and resume it when the game stops after failing (the thread I am appears to be very processor intensive even when it isn't doing anything). I have included some code below, with all the touch event method provided.

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong here? I've looked at a number of threads and tried a number of different approaches, but none have been successful so far.

I have omitted some code to try and keep it clean.

```java
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
...
Thread mainThread;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    paused = true;

    mainThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            synchronized (this) {
                if (paused) {
                    try {
                        paused = false;
                        wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            while (true) {
                if (!paused) {
                    ... GAME STUFF ...
                }
            }
        }
    });
    mainThread.start();
}


public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
    if (e.getPointerCount() == 1) {
        switch (e.getActionMasked()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                if (alertDialog == null) {
                    go();
                } else if (alertDialog.isShowing() == false) {
                    go();
                }
                return true;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                pause();
                saveHighScore();
                dialog("You lifted your finger from the screen! \n" +
                        "You scored " + getScore() + ". \n" +
                        "Your highscore is " + getHighScore());
                reset();
                return true;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (alertDialog == null) {
                    go();
                } else if (alertDialog.isShowing() == false) {
                    if (!checkBounds(e.getX(), e.getY())) {
                        pause();
                        saveHighScore();
                        dialog("You moved outside a circle! \n" +
                                "You scored " + getScore() + ". \n" +
                                "Your high score is " + getHighScore());
                        reset();
                    }
                }

                return true;
        }
    } else {
        pause();
        saveHighScore();
        dialog("You can only use 1 finger at a time! \n" +
                "You scored " + getScore() + ". \n" +
                "Your high score is " + getHighScore());
        reset();
    }

    return true;
}

private synchronized void pause() {
    paused = true;
}

private synchronized void go() {
    if (mainThread.getState() == Thread.State.WAITING) {
        paused = false;
        notify();
    }
}
```

Comment: So it's running, you fail to keep your finger on the circle, and it stops, but never resumes?

Comment: The `ACTION_DOWN` bit calls `go()` as soon as I press on the screen, which should notify the thread to start again.

Comment: I'm new to this. Could you explain to me what alertDialog is in the context of your program?

Comment: The `dialog` method calls a method I wrote that just displays and Android Dialog windows saying "you've failed!". It does not control any game state data. And `reset()` resets some counter values to 0 (used for scoring)

Comment: Whats in the notify method? Do you actually call mainThread.notify(); in a synchronized block? Can't find that anywhere.

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_thread_control.htm

Comment: Changing `notify()` to `mainThread.notify()` results in `java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: object not locked by thread before notify()` as soon as I press on a circle

Comment: Yes you have to first lock the object:     synchronized(mainThread) { mainThread.notify(); }

Comment: @luxer Except the wait() is called on the Runnable object, not the Thread object! Pretty easy to miss...

Comment: obvious `while (true) {` infinite loop is obvious?

Comment: @schmop: which is typically why I avoid the (also quite more verbose) `new Thread(new Runnable(){})` every time i can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your main thread. It starts in a paused state, will get unpaused ONCE, then remain stuck for ever in

```
while (true) {
   if (!paused) {
      ... GAME STUFF ...
   }
}
```

If pause becomes true again, you will just actively loop without ever doing the GAME STUFF. The thread is not sleeping (which is why it is very active without doing anything), so this if statement is never executed

```
if (mainThread.getState() == Thread.State.WAITING) {
    paused = false;
    notify();
}
```

pause will remain true.

You can fix like this:

```
mainThread = new Thread() {public void run() {

        while (true) {
            if (!paused) {
                //... GAME STUFF ...
            }
            else synchronized (this) {
                try {
                    paused = false;
                    wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Also, change the notify() to:

```
synchronized (mainThread) {mainThread.notify();}
```

The wait and notify methods must be called on the same object (inside your thread)

Comment: Sorry, not sure how this helps solve my issue. I understand that the bit where I pause it is unreachable, so I placed it inside the loop, and still no luck.

Comment: @daogle Have you tried exactly the code I provided you?

Comment: @daogle Updated with the wrong notify bit noticed in the comments

Comment: @daogle Notice that the new Thread line changed slightly (and the parenthesis at the end)